# Account Management in IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

I am trying to understand where is the best place for my account management screens.

My project structure is as below:

- IdentityServer
- WebAPI
- SPA

IdentityServer does not provide any UI screens for typical account management.  If you refer to their UI templates (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI) they typcially contain screens for login but nothing for register, reset password, email confirmation etc.

I understand I can use ASP.Net Identity to handle some of this.  My question is where do people typically put the account management screens?  Part of me wants to put them in my Identityserver project so that all everything account related is self contained. I could however also put these screens in the SPA.

Welcome any thoughts on best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have implemented Identity Server 4 a couple times now and I can tell you that you probably won't find so called "best practice". But I will share what I have done.

When it comes to login flows, user registration, password reset, email confirmations - I have just extended the quickstart project that you referred to with custom branding, screens, etc.

When it comes identity, account, client and api resource management - I would create a new web app for that with its own separate backend, however, in all of my projects I used ASP.NET identity and just let the identity database to be shared between IdentityServer4 Auth Server project and the Admin Management UI project.

It is worth noting that the creators of Identity Server 4 also have a commercial option for [Admin UI](https://www.identityserver.com/documentation/admin-ui/). There are also a few open source projects if you browse around that you could potentially take advantage of.